# I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 on Windows 8, now I can't run windows 8

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot

When I power on my Asus laptop an I go to the GNU GRUB area where I have the option to select Windows 8 and Windows recovery environment, but whatever i choose it gives an error.

the error is something like that:

```
Secure boot forbids loading module from  (hd0,gpt7)/boot/grub/ntfs.mod    
no such device:( a number )    
unknown command 'drivemap'.   
invalid EFI drive file.
```

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop (I have tried multiple times to install 14.04 but I had panic errors, so I decided to try 12.04 and it installed properly).
I made a new partition for Ubuntu so I installed them there.

At least I'm sure windows is still installed, but I don't know how to open them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this link:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2148973

Try this link same thing is discussed here also.